# Как превратить массив строковых элементов в массив Jquery-элементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив:

```
arr1 = ["$('#el0')", "$('#el1')", "$('#el2')", "$('#el3')"];
```

Возможно ли превратить его в такой массив:

```
arr2 = [$('#el0'), $('#el1'), $('#el2'), $('#el3')];
```

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: А каким образом у вас получается первый массив?

Comment: Если вы сами делаете такой массив, то лучше делайте массив только из айдишников `['#el0', '#el1', '#el2', '#el3'];`

Comment: Первый массив выдаёт функция, которая его создаёт, в зависимости от длины ещё одного массива. Как то так...

Comment: @benderBey, значит нужно исправить эту функцию

Answer (score 0):

Можно обрезать `"$('` и `')"` методом `.slice()`, получить только селектор и создать новый массив из `jQuery` елементов

```
const arr1 = ["$('#el0')", "$('#el1')", "$('#el2')", "$('#el3')"];

const arr2 = arr1.map(function(item) {
    const id = item.slice(3, -2);
    return $(id);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую. Только я пока не силён в ES6. => это ведь function ()?

Comment: да, очень удобная запись, `(a, b) => { }` это тоже что и `function (a, b) { }` ну не совсем тоже самое, есть отличия с замыканием. Для данного примера можно считать тожесамое

Comment: @AlexanderZaytsev, с замыканием нет отличий

Comment: Всё работает! Спасибо большое.

Comment: @AlexanderZaytsev, и как это связано с замыканием? :)

Comment: @Grundy да спасибо, для меня как-то пересеклись понятия контекста и замыкания в данной ситуации. Освежил знания )